# Getting a CLR stored procedure activated by a broker queue to run as the database owner

Tags: sql-server, filesystems, impersonation, sqlclr, service-broker

I'm trying to set up a CLR stored procedure to be run from a service broker queue so that the CLR stored procedure runs as the database owner.

I've tried all sorts of combinations but can't get this to work without logging in as the user (with username and password) in the CLR stored procedure.

The CLR Stored procedure is accessing the file system and I only want it to be able to access folders allowed for the windows user that owns the database.

Comment: Can you not just use the EXECUTE AS OWNER ?  Sorry, service broker and CLR stored procedures aren't my forte.

Comment: Yes that's what I though, the database is owned by a Windows domain user and my understanding is that activated stored procs run as dbo.

Comment: Microsoft's own documentation at [Impersonation and Credentials for Connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131068%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), has sample code dealing with getting file details within a CLR sproc.

Answer (score 1):

You will never be able to access resources outside SQL Server without providing the password to Windows. EXECUTE AS is only trusted inside the engine, Windows (and hence the file system) has absolutely zero reasons to trust this impersonation sham.

There is one special construct in SQL to facilitate impersonation at os level: [`CREATE CREDENTIAL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189522.aspx), but they work only when mapping a SQL login to a Windows login. Since in your case there is no SQL login to start with, I'm not sure whether you can get SQL Server credentials to work.

Comment: Since this is a CLR stored procedure there is also `WindowsIdentity` and `WindowsImpersonationContext`, etc.  You can in fact even call `LogonUser`, though it is not the preferred solution.

Comment: @joshuadrake the problem with LogonUser is storing the password.

Comment: I felt that the tone of your answer was too strong in the "cannot be done" camp, since the Microsoft example for [Impersonation and Credentials for Connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131068%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) show the access of the Filesystem, which I consider to be resources outside SQL Server, without a password or Create Credential call.

Comment: The example in MSDN deals with impersonating the caller, which is a very different thing. The context can be tracked all the way back to the original NT user login into it's Windows sessions, where it had presented the password. In an SSB activated context this chain doesn't exists, because SSB activated context sessions are background sessions started by the engine. As such they would require to call `LogonUser` to create an NT context, which would pose the (nontrivial) problem of having access to the account password.